# Can I create another bot user from an existed one in Slack?

Tags: chatbot, slack, slack-api

I need to create one more the same bot user after some conversations with the first bot (I need to have kind of recursion).
I can to do it, but I need to have another "slack bot oauth access token" for it.

So, the owner need to go to the Slack Api portal and to make a new APP, add a new bot, and after he will have the token. But it is not pretty and is not easy for the user. Do we have any ways to automate the process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one bot user per Slack app. If you want to deploy multiple bot users, you also need to create multiple Slack apps.

So, what you can not do is adding additional bot users to an existing Slack app. Even if you go though the Oauth process again to get a different bot token, the bot user is still the same.